# Slimselect: selecting second option after searching not working

Tags: javascript, plugins

I asked this question by [gitHub](https://github.com/brianvoe/slim-select/issues/217), but I try it here as well maybe someone knows the issue.

I am using [slim select plugin](https://slimselectjs.com/), when I try to select the second option after searching I get an error

see picture:
[image: see picture]

But when I click outside so that the drop down goes closed and start searching again then I can select many options without getting the error.

Here is the code snippet where slimselect is initialized:

```
function initDropDowns () {

    $('[slimselect]').each(function (index) {
        var id                 = $(this).attr("id");
        var placeholder        = $(this).data("placeholder");
        var selectByGroup      = true;
        var compareDropDown    = false;
        var dataSelectByGroup  = $(this).data("selectbygroup");
        var dataCmpareDropdown = $(this).data("comparedropdown");

        if (dataSelectByGroup) {
            selectByGroup = dataSelectByGroup === "true";
        }
        if (dataCmpareDropdown) {
            compareDropDown = dataCmpareDropdown === "true";
        }

        var that = this;
        var select = new SlimSelect({
            select:     '#' + id,
            placeholder: placeholder,
            showSearch:  true,
            searchText: settings.texts.noSearchResults,
            searchPlaceholder: settings.texts.searchPlaceholder,
            searchingText: settings.texts.searchingText,
            searchHighlight: true,
            closeOnSelect: false,
            showOptionTooltips: true,
            selectByGroup: selectByGroup,
            hideSelectedOption:true,
            limit: 5,
            beforeOnChange: function (info) {
                if ($(that).data('singleselect') === true) {
                    dropDowns[that.id].set ([]);
                }
            },
            onChange: slimSelectOnChange
        });
        dropDowns[id] = select;
    });
}
```